# writing unicode to binary file in python

Tags: python, unicode, file-io

I'm wondering how to write unicode (utf-8) to a binary file.  Here's the background: I've got a 40 byte header (10 ints), and a table with a variable number of triple-int structs.  Writing these was cake.

Now, I want to add a bunch of strings to the end of the file.

Writing regular ASCII based strings is easy:

```
value = ('ab')
s = struct.Struct('2s')
packed_data = s.pack(value)
```

I learned how to do this from the [Interpret strings as packed binary data](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html).

But is there a way to do this for unicode (utf-8) based strings?

Any ideas?  Has anyone done this before?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish.  UTF-8 is a method of encoding _character_ data.  It should have no bearing on writing binary data.  In fact, if you write arbitrary binary data to a UTF-8 stream you should get errors when you accidentally introduce invalid encodings.  Please clarify with some sample data and expected output.

Comment: UTF-8 *is* binary data, and not Unicode. Standard link on Unicode: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unicode != UTF-8.  UTF-8 is a binary encoding of Unicode, so just write the UTF-8 string just as you would an ASCII string.  No need to pack an encoded string either.  It's already "just a bunch of bytes".

```
# coding: utf8
import struct
text = u'我是美国人。'
encoded_text = text.encode('utf8')

# proof packing is redundant...
format = '{0}s'.format(len(encoded_text))
packed_text = struct.pack(format,encoded_text)
print encoded_text == packed_text # result: True
```

So just encode your Unicode strings and append them to the file after writing your packed ints.

Comment: By the use of pack I inferred he was writing other bynary data with the strings; If he is not, pack is indeed reduntand...

Comment: Yes, and it can be used to zero-pad the string to a specific length.  It just depends what he wants to do.

Answer (score 2):

unicode.encode('utf-8') will return a byte string encoded in UTF-8; just check for the length before packing.