# google app engine download a file containing files

Tags: python, google-app-engine, download

Okay, I have:

```
class Content(db.Model):
    code=db.TextProperty()
```

And there are 3 different values of code stored in the database. How would I create a zip file that stores the three values of code in 3 separate files that would be downloaded?

Based on eric.f's answer:
I rewrote his code to make it to do what I wanted:

```
    contents = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Content ORDER BY created DESC")
    output = StringIO.StringIO()
    with zipfile.ZipFile(output, 'w') as myzip:
        for content in contents:
            if content.code:
                code=content.code
            else:
                code=content.code2
            myzip.writestr('udacity_code'+`content.key().id()`, code)
    self.response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/zip"
    self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=test.zip"
    self.response.out.write(output.getvalue())
```

I got an error though...

```
self.response.out.write(output.getvalue(), "utf-8")
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/StringIO.py", line 270, in getvalue
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb4 in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: are you using unicode in code? if not just make sure all the code are ascii before writing to zipfile, try using str(code) instead of code in writestr()

Comment: code contains python code that users submit.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542961/writing-unicode-to-binary-file-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import zipfile
import StringIO

output = StringIO.StringIO()

with zipfile.ZipFile(output, 'w') as myzip:
    myzip.writestr('file1.txt', 'aaaaaaaaa')
    myzip.writestr('file2.txt', 'bbbbbbbbb')
    myzip.writestr('file3.txt', 'ccccccccc')
```

then make your response, set `output.getvalue()` as the content, and set headers as below:

```
Content-type: application/zip
Content-disposition: attachment; filename=test.zip
```

Comment: Could you look over my code to see if you know what to do? (The value of `content.code` and `content.code2` are formatted python code) I really need your help... Thanks!

Comment: Thank you... I figured it out!